# Constant Pointer vs Constant Variable

Tags: c

Im new to C programming and I'd like to know how does a pointer constant differ from a constant variable in this case:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void) 
{ 
   int cnt = 0;        

   char val; 
   char mystr[20] = “hello there!”; 
   char *p_str2, str2[20] = “zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz”; 
   char* p_mystr = mystr; 

   p_str2 = str2; 

   while (*p_mystr != 0x00)
   {
       val=*p_mystr++; 
       cnt++; 
   } 

   return 0; 
}
```

also, how does `mystr` differ from `mystr[2]` (what data type is each variable) and is there anything wrong with `p_mystr = mystr[2];` could this be written better (ie: why is `*p_mystr= mystr[2];` correct)?

Comment: You strongly need [this](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html)!

Comment: Also consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c

Comment: There is no "pointer constant" or "constant variable" here, so your first question is unclear.

Comment: The only constants in that example are your string literals (and possibly the integer literals as well, depending on your platform)... Also, consider that a pointer is usually stored in a "variable" (although variables obviously aren't always pointers)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  The result is not an *lvalue*, meaning it cannot be the target of an assignment.

So, given the declaration

```
char mystr[20] = "hello there!";
```

the following are all true:

```
  Expression        Type            Decays to      Result
  ----------        ----            ---------      ------
       mystr        char [20]       char *         address of mystr[0]
      &mystr        char (*)[20]    n/a            address of mystr
      *mystr        char            n/a            value of mystr[0], or 'h'
    mystr[i]        char            n/a            i'th character
   &mystr[i]        char *          n/a            address of mystr[i]
sizeof mystr        size_t          n/a            20 (number of bytes in array)
```

The address of the array is the same as the address of the first element of the array (no storage is set aside for a `mystr` variable separate from the array elements themselves), so the expressions `mystr`, `&mystr` and `&mystr[0]` all return the same *value*, but the types of the expressions are different; `mystr` and `&mystr[0]` both have type `char *`, but `&mystr` has type `char (*)[20]`, or "pointer to 20-element array of `char`".

The results for `str2` are the same.

Given the declaration

```
char *p_mystr;
```

we get the following

```
    Expression      Type        Result
    ----------      ----        ------
       p_mystr      char *      value in p_mystr
      *p_mystr      char        value of character pointed to by p_mystr
      &p_mystr      char **     address of p_mystr variable
sizeof p_mystr      size_t      number of bytes in pointer value
```

The table for `p_str2` is the same.

Now it's a matter of matching up types.  `p_mystr = mystr` works because both expressions have type `char *`; `p_mystr` winds up pointing to `mystr[0]`.  Similarly, `*p_mystr = mystr[2]` works<sup>1</sup> because both expressions have type `char`.  Same for `val = *p_mystr++`, although note in this case that `*p_mystr++` is parsed as `*(p_mystr++)`; the increment will be applied to the *pointer* value, not the character value.

Note that an expression like `p_mystr = &mystr;` should get you a diagnostic to the effect that the types don't match.

Your question title mentions `const` pointers and variables, although that doesn't appear in the question body.  Basically, for any type `T`:

```
T *p0;                 // p0 is a non-const pointer to non-const T
const T *p1;           // p1 is a non-const pointer to const T
T const *p2;           // p2 is a non-const pointer to const T
T * const p3;          // p3 is a const pointer to non-const T
const T * const p4;    // p4 is a const pointer to const t
T const * const p5;    // p5 is a const pointer to const t
```

Which breaks down as:

- You can write to `p0` (change it to point to something else) and `*p0` (change the thing being pointed to);
- You can write to `p1` and `p2` (change them to point to something else), but you cannot write to `*p1` or `*p2` (cannot change the thing being pointed to);
- You cannot write to `p3` (cannot change it to point to something else), but you can write to `*p3` (change the thing being pointed to);
- You cannot write to `p4` or `p5` (cannot change them to point to something else), nor can you write to `*p4` or `*p5` (cannot change the thing being pointed to).

So, if you declared something like

```
const char *cptr = mystr;
```

you could not modify the contents of `mystr` through the `cptr` variable, even though `mystr` is not declared `const` itself.

Note that trying to go the other way, such as

```
const int foo = 5;
int *fptr = (int *) &foo;
*fptr = 6;
```

invokes undefined behavior; it may or may not work, depending on the implementation (the language definition allows implementations to put `const`-qualified objects in read-only memory).

---

<sup>1. *If* `p_mystr` is pointing somewhere valid, that is.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Both your variables `mystr` and `str2` are character arrays stored on the stack. There's nothing "constant" here, except the string literals used to initialize your character arrays.

---

`p_mystr` is a pointer, `mystr[2]` is a character. *Where* is your `*p_mystr= mystr[2];` supposed to be? It better not be *before* `p_mystr`'s initialization to a valid address.

Answer (score 0):

You just asked a mouthful!

1. A pointer is a very different type to a simple data type (a char * compared to a char).  A char just has a single value e.g. 'a'.  You can think of a pointer as a memory address - it means, go to the memory address 0x0123F1A and treat what you find there as a char.  Pointers can be tricky to get your head around so it's worth reading up on e.g.  [here](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm)
2. mystr is an array of characters.  In some ways it will behave like a pointer to the first item in the array, but it is genuinely a distinct type. mystr[2] has type char - it is the char found at index 2 in the array (i.e. the third char since array indices start at 0).
3. There is nothing wrong with p_mystr = mystr - it is safe to assign from a char-array to a char-pointer, and the meaning is to make the pointer point to the first item in the array.
4. *p_mystr=mystr[2] means something else.  The * operator means "the value pointed to", so what this means is "in the memory address where p_mystr is pointing, copy the character mystr[2]"